# jquery mobile datebox Link straight to specific month

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying out Jquery Mobile DateBox.

See here: http://dev.jtsage.com/

I want wondering if anyone know how I could create a link to a specific month and have the calendar popup on that specified month.

Anyone have any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure use the default date option

```
"defaultDate" : "08-01-2011"
```

Answer (score 1):

Date is in an incorrect format in the accepted answer. Should be:

```
"defaultDate" : "2011-01-25"
```